# Is it a coincidence that Supergirl's original name in the comics was Linda Lee and Red Daughter posed as "Linda lee?"

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl-2015

If you look on [the *Arrowverse* Fandom page Red Daughter](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Red_Daughter), Linda Lee is one of the "codenames" for Red Daughter. You see Red Daughter using the alias "Linda Lee" in episode 4x16 of *Supergirl,* and Linda Lee was the original Supergirl (in the comics, she was known a Linda Lee Danvers, and in the original Supergirl movies she was just Linda Lee). Were the writers paying homage, or was it just coincidence?

Comment: In the comics, the alias Supergirl chose in _[Action Comics Vol 1 #252](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_252)_ was originally just Linda Lee as well. It became Linda Lee Danvers after she was adopted by Fred and Edna Danvers in _[Action Comics Vol 1 #279](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_279)_.

Comment: Its just an easter egg

Comment: Given how many references the *Supergirl* show has to older comics and movies, I never doubted that the name Linda Lee was very deliberately chosen. (BTW, one of the subtler references is that the grafitti beside to door to Al's Dive Bar spells "BAR" in interlac, the future alphabet introduced in 1980s *Legion of Super-Heroes*.)